# How to set parallel step results in Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I'm running some tests with Jenkins Pipeline using parallelism and I noticed that Blue Ocean behaves weirdly with job results. I declared a global class with a variable to handle the current build status based on the parallel jobs results.

It works, however the parallel steps status does not seem to be getting set correctly within the Blue Ocean UI.

I prepared an example below to show what is going on. The pipeline definition is:

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('Tests') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel(
                      a: {
                        echo "This is branch a"
                        manager.build.@result = hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS
                      },
                      b: {
                        echo "This is branch b"
                        manager.build.@result = hudson.model.Result.ABORTED
                      },
                      c: {
                        echo "This is branch c"
                        manager.build.@result = hudson.model.Result.UNSTABLE
                      },
                      d: {
                        echo "This is branch d"
                        manager.build.@result = hudson.model.Result.FAILURE
                        try {sh "exit 1"}catch(e){echo 'failure'}
                      }
                    )
                    manager.build.@result = hudson.model.Result.UNSTABLE
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The last row changes the build result correctly (whatever value I give it - SUCCESS, FAILURE, UNSTABLE or ABORTED).

However, the result for each parallel step are always SUCCESS. The only exception is when I give the general build the status of UNSTABLE, then all parallel steps become UNSTABLE as well. Below follows an illustration:

[image: UI error representation]

I expected each parallel step to have it's own result, it would be very useful for debugging test results, since I need to run tests in different machines / devices in parallel.

Is it a Blue Ocean problem or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I believe this is an answer to your question - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45579

Comment: Hum you are right, it seems like a feature not ready yet, thanks!